# NuGet packages built and published to TC own feed don't show up

Tags: teamcity-9.0, nuget-server

Q/A - Today, we found that a NuGet library build and publish (to TeamCity's own feed) stopped working. The new packages stopped showing up.

We can see them in the artifacts but not in the feed itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By querying the feed with PowerShell it appeared that the packages up to build 9 were showing, so I suspected a problem with 1.1.xx.0 where xx are double-digit numbers.

I published 1.2.0.0 and it showed up. Odd! Here's the proof:

[image: Feed vs. artifacts]

**Edit**

Today, both VS and NuGet restore on TeamCity cannot see a new version of a library on the feed even though I can see it directly in the feed XML!!

What the??

**Solution**

Since updating the ver of TC to 9.1.5 the URL that TC thinks is its own feed is missing the port number of the TC server! So NuGet package restore is getting a 404 from that feed.

My PS script was using the feed URL that I have set in VS which has the port.